# python and pygame font centering is working but I don't know why

Tags: python, fonts, pygame, sdl

My code is working perfectly although I'm completely in the dark as to why.

my code is:

```
def textobjects(message, font,color):
    Textsurface = font.render(message, True, color)
    return Textsurface, Textsurface.get_rect()

def Display_text(message,color):
    Heading = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial",70)
    TextShown, Textrect = textobjects(message, Heading,color)
    Textrect.center = ((displaywidth/2),0)
    gameWindow.blit(TextShown,Textrect)
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(2)
    game_loop()


def border():
    Display_text("You hit the border",wine)
```

and I don't know why I was able to do:

```
Textrect.center = ((displaywidth/2),0)
```

without having to define ".center". Is .center a pygame/python predefined module?

Comment: And yes, pygame.Rect has a attitude called center. But I highly recommend you starting from a most basic example

Comment: It's not completely my code, no. I was just watching a video tutorial and was curious to know why it worked. Thank you for replying.

Comment: Where could I find basic examples for a beginner (myself) ?

Comment: @chubel Here are two links that will help: http://pygame.org/docs/tut/newbieguide.html and http://pygame.org/docs/

Comment: I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

.center is a part of a rect object that you can both get and set

You can also do

```
Rect.left
Rect.top
Rect.right
Rect.bottom
Rect.topleft
Rect.bottomleft
Rect.topright
Rect.bottomright
Rect.centerx
Rect.centery
```